# How to create a new unique identifier for father and children registers where i just have the reading order?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to create a new unique identifier for father and children registers considering a table structure where I have the first row identified by `C100` and the next rows identified by `C170`?
Table structure:

```
|C100|0|1|2001118|...
|C170|1|7385|...
|C170|2|15904|...
|C170|3|15975|...
|C170|4|15840|...
|C100|0|1|2015356|...
|C170|1|23194|...
|C100|0|1|2015356|...
|C170|1|20833|...
|C170|2|20836|...
|C170|3|20837|...
|C170|4|20838|...
|C170|5|20839|...
|C170|6|20840|...
|C170|7|20841|...
|C170|8|20842|...
|C170|9|20843|...
|C170|10|20845|...
|C170|11|20846|...
```

Note: This is an external table created over a formatted file where each row is in sequence by reading.
For register `C170` the second column is ordering by number (1:N), but not the same when register is `C100`, because when register equal to `C100` the next column would be 0 or 1.

To be more elusive, `C100` is the father and each row named `C170` under this `C100` row are the children.
I would like to do something like this:

```
|1|C100|0|1|2001118|...
|1|C170|1|7385|...
|1|C170|2|15904|...
|1|C170|3|15975|...
|1|C170|4|15840|...
|2|C100|0|1|2015356|...
|2|C170|1|23194|...
|3|C100|0|1|2015356|...
|3|C170|1|20833|...
|3|C170|2|20836|...
|3|C170|3|20837|...
|3|C170|4|20838|...
|3|C170|5|20839|...
|3|C170|6|20840|...
|3|C170|7|20841|...
|3|C170|8|20842|...
|3|C170|9|20843|...
|3|C170|10|20845|...
|3|C170|11|20846|...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
select sum(case register when 'C100' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by rownum) ind
     , t1.*
  from Your_Table t1;
```